# chrome.devtools.* support across versions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

im writing an extention that uses chrome.devtools, in particular **chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow** and **chrome.devtools.network**, It seems that my chrome version 18.0.1025.151 does not support these api's, I wonder where can I find which functions are supported since which version?
Maybe someone can tell me how i debug the **devtools_page**? if it crashes i dont see no indication of it anywhere...
Thanks in advance.
also - it seems like the devtools api's are present... 
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got my solution, it turns out that the **manifest_version** field was set to version 2 which is what was blocking my functions, which seems weird because it says in the docs that v2 is 18 and above and not 19 and above :-/

Comment: I also had some problems with `manifest_version: 2`: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125169 . This functionality seems to be unstable, it's better not to use it for now.

Answer (score 2):

I looked for the same thing some time ago and the best resources that I found are these:

- [What's new in each Chrome version (regarding extensions)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html)
- [List of all API's available in current stable version](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html)
- [Release information about each new Chrome version](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/)

As to devtools debuging:

- undock devtools window (button in the bottom left)
- focus devtools window
- click F12

And now you are debugging your devtools with devtools :) Checkout [this](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! I wish the community were more responsive, maybe a special gargon?

Comment: I've updated my answer with details about debugging (I missed that part of your question earlier). Good luck!

Comment: Hm, I recently worked on devtools extension to and I always got all of my errors on the other devtools console. Maybe it's your background.html that creates errors? Or maybe a content script?